# logback logging in oracle causes dialect error

Tags: oracle, slf4j, logback

I set up database logging with `slf4j` and `logback`. I use this configuration with `postgresql` and `sqlite` without any problem

```
<appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
    <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DataSourceConnectionSource">
        <dataSource class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
            <driverClassName>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClassName><!-- org.sqlite.JDBC-->
            <jdbcUrl>jdbc.postgresql://host:port/db_name</jdbcUrl><!-- jdbc:sqlite:local/dir/path/db_name.db-->
            <username>username</username>
            <password>password</password>
        </dataSource>
    </connectionSource>
</appender>
```

Now I want to send all these logs to **oracle db** so I changed the config file respectively

```
<appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
    <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DataSourceConnectionSource">
        <dataSource class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
            <driverClassName>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driverClassName>
            <jdbcUrl>jdbc:oracle:thin:blabal@x.x.x.x:port:oraserv</jdbcUrl>
            <username>user</username>
            <password>pass</password>
        </dataSource>
    </connectionSource>
    <sqlDialect class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.dialect.OracleDialect" />
</appender>
```

But I got this error

```
15:45:05,832 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@25:76 - no applicable action for [sqlDialect], current ElementPath is [[configuration][appender][sqlDialect]]
15:45:05,837 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@26:16 - RuntimeException in Action for tag [appender] java.lang.IllegalStateException: DBAppender cannot function if the JDBC driver does not support getGeneratedKeys method *and* without a specific SQL dialect
```

[image]

I thought dialect configuration through xml would solve the problem, but nothing changed.
Can you give me some advice to make it work with oracle?

Comment: There were mismatches in official document. I had to change `driverClass` to `driverClassName` and `user` to `username`. Took me the whole day to fix it.

Comment: Please post an answer and mark it as accepted then.

Comment: I still can't make it work on oracle. The mismatch I mentioned only solved part of the problem. Sorry for the ambiguous comment

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out just now. 
I guess you thought the "supporting getGeneratedKeys" means that logback can generate tables and fields for you? 
The answer is NO.
In any case, you should run the scripts provided by logback in its zip file to build the tables by yourself.
"getGeneratedKeys" is just another function, and logback supports it, which means you need not config the sqlDialect any more, from 0.9.*, you just need ignore the "sqlDialect".

Comment: I had the tables generated before running the code. The tables says that dialect is provided by _logback_ but the error `no applicable action for [sqlDialect]`. I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Try to delete this token. Maybe the default configuration had already contains it.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<appender name="db-classic-oracle" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">  
        <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">  
            <dataSource class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">              
                <driverClass>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driverClass>  
                <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ZYD</url>  
                <user>scott</user>  
                <password>tiger</password>
                <sqlDialect class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.dialect.OracleDialect" />   
            </dataSource>  
        </connectionSource>
    </appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with Mysql. Eventually I figured it out. I don't know if it is any help for you but here is my configuration (groovy)

```
appender('DB', DBAppender) {
  connectionSource(DataSourceConnectionSource) {
    dataSource(MysqlDataSource) {
      url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/ts-mtt"
    }
    user = "root"
    password = ""
  }
}
```

The sqlDialect should not be added. Also as you see user and password are properties of a connectionSource. I hope it is any help.