# logback logging in PostgreSQL causes dialect error

Tags: java, xml, postgresql, logback

I'm working on an application that uses logback for logging.

I used the logback `DBAppender` to insert logs into DB.

All worked great for me and I was able to insert and see the logs into the database.

My configuration looks like the below:

```
                  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                      <configuration debug="true"> 
                      <!-- Note that i'm using postgreSQL: -->



 <appender name="DBAppPostgreSQL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
        <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
            <dataSource class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
                  <driverClass>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClass>
                  <url>jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5678/DB</url>
                  <user>test</user>
                  <password>password</password>
            </dataSource>
        </connectionSource>
        <sqlDialect class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        <insertHeaders>true</insertHeaders>
</appender>



  <root level="debug">
      <appender-ref ref="DBAppPostgreSQL" />
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

The logback's internal status is:

```
   09:37:04,755 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@26:89 - no applicable action for [sqlDialect], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][connectionSource[dataSource[sqlDialect]]
```

CAn you give suggetion what is missing in code ?

I also refer [logback logging in oracle causes dialect error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059184/logback-logging-in-oracle-causes-dialect-error) but i didn't resolve error

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you have the same issue as this question:
[Asynchronous DBAppender with logback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928091/asynchronous-dbappender-with-logback)

You need to change the `DriverManagerConnectionSource` in the `connectionSource` to `DataSourceConnectionSource`